# What is a wrapper_descriptor, and why is Foo.__init__() one in this case?

Tags: python, initialization

```
import inspect

class Foo(object):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print type(Foo.__init__)
    print inspect.getsourcelines(Foo.__init__)
```

Output:

```
<type 'wrapper_descriptor'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  *snip*
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/inspect.py", line 420, in getfile
    'function, traceback, frame, or code object'.format(object))
TypeError: <slot wrapper '__init__' of 'object' objects> is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object
```

Googling gives very little useful information about what, exactly, a wrapper_descriptor is, and why an empty class has an `__init__` method that is not a method, but rather a wrapper_descriptor.

What exactly is going on here? Do all classes without `__init__` methods have one of these wrapper_descriptor things? Why is there an `__init__` in the class dict at all?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you've run into is an implementation detail. This is pretty typical for classes implemented in C, as `object` is. It's not a Python method, it is a C method, and the wrapper is part of this interface.

> Why is there an `__init__` in the class dict at all?

It's not in the class dict, it's in the `object` dict. `object` has an `__init__` so that when you try to call your class's base classes' `__init__` methods using `super()`, it doesn't fail.

Comment: The C API documentation explains some of the details beyond this, if you care. But normally you don't care beyond the fact that "slot wrapper", "method-wrapper", and similar are things that you can call as if they were bound methods, unbound methods, etc., but don't have any Python source code.

Comment: this wrapper_description has no __annotations__ member, any way to bypass this non generalization