# Inconsistence among built-in types and user defined

Tags: python, types

While reading about the [unification of types](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/#introspection) I stumbled on the fact that  built-in types have `method_descriptor`s and `builtin_function_or_method`s instead of `method`s and `function`s, why?

```
>>> list.append
<method 'append' of 'list' objects>
>>> type(list.append)
<class 'method_descriptor'>
>>> [].append
<built-in method append of list object at 0x7f0c4214aef0>
>>> type([].append)
<class 'builtin_function_or_method'>
>>> class A(list):
...   def append(self): pass
... 
>>> A.append
<function A.append at 0x7f0c42168dd0>
>>> type(A.append)
<class 'function'>
>>> A().append
<bound method A.append of []>
>>> type(A().append)
<class 'method'>
```

There is no good reason for `class A` to subclass list, I just wanted to show that the types differ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Difference lies in fact that built-ins are C-compiled code descriptors, whereas user-defined functions represent iterpreted code [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html). See [source](https://github.com/python-git/python/blob/715a6e5035bb21ac49382772076ec4c630d6e960/Objects/descrobject.c#L386) for details.

Also, while built-ins and their methods are statically allocated data structures, memory for user-defined data structures is allocated dinamically. Even sizes differs: size of descriptors is equal among built-in functions as well as among similar user-defined, refer to C source (link above):

```
>>> sys.getsizeof(list.append)
72   # built-in
>>> sys.getsizeof(dir)
72   # built-in
>>> sys.getsizeof(A.__init__)
80   # class/instance method
>>> sys.getsizeof(lambda x: x)
120  # static function
```

So those things look different, resides in different places and behave different. There is no need to give them equal names.

I would like to add missed compiled analogue for [`classmethod`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod), `classmethod_descriptor`,

```
>>> type(float.__dict__['fromhex'])
<type 'classmethod_descriptor'>
```

and some other interesting types:

```
>>> type(A.__init__)
<type 'wrapper_descriptor'>
>>> type(A.__dict__['__dict__'])
<type 'getset_descriptor'>
```

See:

1. [What is a wrapper_descriptor, and why is `Foo.__init__` one in this case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15512433/1265154)
2. [What is the `__dict__.__dict__` attribute of a Python class?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4877655/1265154)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I understand that there is a implementation difference, but I want to know why these methods need to be of different types. Is there a compatibility reason, or it just ended up being like that and did not create any problems?

Comment: @hack.augusto I tried to add some more explanation, see if it helps