# Why do Types return True in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, types

Am I right in my understanding that the `if` statement will only 'execute' if it evaluates `True`?

If so, what is the purpose of *types* returning `True`?

What is the logic behind this rule?

Can someone give me an example of where it would be useful?

example:

```
""" Example """

def test(x):
    if float:
        print("success")

test(9)
test('\ntesting')
```

Returns:

[image]

Comment: Now try `test(0)` and `test("")`

Comment: Why? His argument is not used in the function at all.  Float returns true, his function will always print success when called.  He's asking why float, as a type, returns true.

Comment: @Kevin - tried both, also prints success

Comment: Haha, oops, misread. Thought it said `if x:`

Comment: of course they do, you don't use the argument. you could pass anything, it would still return true.

Comment: here is the doc... https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

Comment: `float` doesn't *return* true -- it *is* true (or at least "truthy")

Comment: Yes and that's my question: Why do types return true? 

My question was not: Why does returning True to an If statement execute the body of the if statement.

Comment: @John - so even the if statement will be executed if anything True or "Truthy" is passed to it?

Are there other examples of things that the If statement accepts?

Comment: `Why do types return true?` read the doc, it says `All other values are considered true`. Basically some specific values are False, all the others are True by default.

Comment: @njzk2 thank you! Would you like to write this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: For future reference: you would have gotten less confusion if you only included the code that releated to your specific question, i.e. `if float: print('float is true?')`.  The fact that you have a function that you pass a parameter and call it with different parameters in your example is very confusing and led to at least one answer that had nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @RubenBaden Out of curiosity, do you think it should be false? Or do you think (did you think) this should be some kind of error?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I didn't really have an opinion on the matter before; Just something that I noticed and was curious about.

If you are asking me about my opinion of this logic now that I have an answer? 

Well I don't claim to know any better than Python developers when it comes to language architecture - So for the present time i'm going to assume that conditional statements should always evaluate true unless we use one of the clearly defined false typ because (**disclaimer** 2nd degree assumption) otherwise it leads to an environment where the functionality of conditionals is too limited.

Comment: @SethMMorton Ahh you're right - I apologize to the community for a too hastily assembled question.

Your example was much more concise.

Comment: @RubenBaden Don't worry about it.  Extracting the root of the problem from a larger example is a skill that needs to be developed; I was just trying to help develop that skill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From docs :

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while
>   condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following
>   values are considered false:
>
> None
>
> False
>
> zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0L, 0.0, 0j.
>
> any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
>
> any empty mapping, for example, {}.
>
> instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a
>   __nonzero__() or __len__() method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False. [1]
>
> **> All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are
>   always true.**
>
> Operations and built-in functions that have a Boolean result always
>   return 0 or False for false and 1 or True for true, unless otherwise
>   stated. (Important exception: the Boolean operations or and and always
>   return one of their operands.)

Since all types are derived from object, `__nonzero__` doesn't return False or integer zero and they don't have `__len__` method, it is considered as True.

There is another interesting thing:
`__nonzero__` of float is `<slot wrapper '__nonzero__' of 'float' objects>`

Here is some info about that: 
[What is a wrapper_descriptor, and why is Foo.__init__() one in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512183/what-is-a-wrapper-descriptor-and-why-is-foo-init-one-in-this-case)

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/295354/what-is-the-reasoning-for-presence-of-value-evaluating-as-truthy-in-python-e

Answer (score 3):

All objects (including types, which are instances of `type`) are inherently true because they represent the presence of a value of the underlying type, as opposed to `None` which represents the absence of a value of any type. (It's not useful for `None` to evaluate to true just because it is an instance of `NoneType`.)

Some instances of certain types (empty strings and the empty instances of container types, to name a few) evaluate to `False` instead because it is convenient to consider them so.

In your own classes, you can override the truth value of a particular instance by overriding either [`__nonzero__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) or `__len__` to return 0 or `False` for a particular instance.

Comment: I replaced Float with None and it failed to print!

Thank you so much for this answer. Makes sense to me now!

Answer (score -2):

The  basic question is:

> What is the logic behind this rule?

This rule is there to **define** how Python (should) operate: whenever there is an if-statement with an value other as `True` or `False` the results should be clear. And the same for all implementations!

It does *not* imply it's a good style. Nor that one should use it

```
if float(3.14):
    print("is not a proper way to program")
 else:
    print("even it is clearly defined what will happen")
```

Personal, I have no clue what will be printed. And I will not look it up, as it is bad anyhow. I always tell my class: "*Even when the compiler understand it, your college will not"*

Comment: Are you saying that leveraging truthy and falsey values like `if my_list:` or `if result:` is poor style that should not be used?

Comment: It depends. Surely True and False are clear for everyone. If your audience are no expert stick to them.  But library code, by example,  is read only by experts, so there are more types are allowed. Personally

Comment: If your audience is not expert, you should be telling them about truthy and falsey values instead of showing them fake, bad code.

Comment: It depends. Surely True and False are clear for everyone. If your audience are no expert stick to them.  But library code, by example,  is read only by experts, so there are more types are allowed. Then, even user-classes can be fine to use. But don't a type is, if you have to look it up! Make it explicit! Personal, I prefer to check for an empty list/sequence , then trust an empty one is false. (And hope everybody knows)

Comment: What do you mean, "trust an empty one is false"? Of course an empty `list` evaluates to a falsey value. It's totally intentional, and it's meant to let you write neater, clearer code. Writing code that avoids this fact (plus whatever other language features you've arbitrarily deemed unusable) will simply result in worse code, and using it as any kind of teaching aid in any context will do nothing but give readers a worse understanding of Python. This answer is very misleading.

Comment: Not all users are, or should be/become (programming) experts. By example, many people in my classes are testers. They are experts in there field and use Python (scripts) for automated tests. Or are expert programmers, in another language. It will help them to make it explicit and simple

Comment: No, you're helping them make code that's unnecessarily crufty and complicated. Why are you afraid of teaching them something as simple and useful as this? Does each new fact push an old one out of their heads? On top of that, people on SO's Python tag are _actually trying to learn Python_, so your justification of your extremely questionable teaching methods doesn't even apply here.

Comment: Let's not start a flame-war! We agree Python is fine. And (I guess) assuming that an empty sequence is False is/should be known by all Python programmers  the question was about why is it defined for all cases. And the sub-question was: should we use them, or can it become bad style? My remarks is it can become bad style. But leave it to the questioner where the gray areas are. Ok?

Comment: No. It's never bad style, and your answer basically says it's always bad style. Personally, if I posted a misleading, harmful answer like this and then was informed of how bad it was, I would delete it.