# Get number of args for function

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, inline, subclassing

I have a module, `ui`. I'd like to get a list of all the classes that `ui` defines which are a subclass of `ui.View`, and that can be called without arguments.

I've tried the following code:

```
ui_elements=[d for d in ui.__dict__.values() if type(d)==type and inspect.getargspec(d.__init__)[0]==1 and isinstance(d(),ui.View)]
```

But I get the following error from inside the `inspect` module:

```
TypeError: <slot wrapper '__init__' of 'object' objects> is not a Python function
```

I'm using `inspect` instead of a `try:` `except:` just because checking beforehand seems like a better solution than trying it to see if it works.

So, how can I get a list of all the classes that subclass `ui.View` and do not require arguments to create? I'd like to do this inline if possible, and I'd also like to avoid using `try:`/`except:` statements.

Comment: Note that you can use `issubclass` rather than trying to initialise them. Also, you could take failing to initialise them with no parameters as a sign that they require parameters - why the requirement for inline/no `try`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I guess I thought `try` was a pretty in-pythonic way to count arguments. Is there a better way?

Comment: It's not very Pythonic to count parameters! Handling errors is idiomatic; *"it is easier to ask forgiveness than permission"*. Could you take a step back and describe the broader problem you're trying to solve? That way we avoid [XY problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248731).

Comment: I'm using a Python distribution that includes a `ui` module. It's got a lot of different UI elements, all of which subclass `ui.View`. I'd like to make a `ui.View` with sub views for each type of UI element. I'm avoiding the ones that take extra arguments purely for simplicity's sake.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the additional context.

Comment: Just *try* to create them and catch the exceptions when creating them doesn't work.  Having arguments doesn't mean that one cannot be made without them.  They can be optional.

Comment: @Alfe Yeah, that works if there's not a better way.

Comment: It seems to be necessary to explain (in the question) why you consider using introspection tools (like `inspect`) to count the number of arguments "better" than doing the simple `try`/`except` routine.

Comment: @Alfe It's inline, and more pythonic probably.

Comment: You cannot *really* check beforehand, that's the core of our disagreement.  If you check the number of arguments you might get classes which cannot be instantiated on Tuesdays.  But you will not get the ones which have an optional argument for the background color.  That would be two wrong predicates.  And you *still* didn't give a reason why checking beforehand would be any better than trying and handling errors.

Comment: @Alfe ok, I see your point. Try/catch is good enough. I was trying to see if I could get it into a single list comprehension, but that's not a requirement.

Comment: Is the module `ui` written by you? Can you add a list to that module that has all of the zero-argument Views in it? Or can you make them all a subclass of View that takes no arguments and then simple do `issubclass`?

Comment: @daveydave400 No, it's a part of [Pythonista](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/index.html). Since it's an iOS app, built in modules are part of `PythonistaKit.framework`, and are therefore sandboxed and completely inaccessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list comprehension with `try`/`except` you can use a local function:

```
def tryCreate(class_):
  try:
    return class_()
  except:
    return None

ui_elements = set(tryCreate(d) for d in ui.__dict__.values()
    if issubclass(d, ui.View)) - set(None)
```

Okay, it's a set comprehension in the end ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As said in comments, you should use `try/catch`, but if you really want to do it that way...

First, use `inspect` to check if your symbol is a class, use `issubclass` as suggested in comments and you want the number of arguments to be 1, not the first argument to be 1. So, something like this:

```
ui_elements = [ d for d in ui.__dict__.values()
    if (inspect.isclass(d) and
        issubclass(d, ui.View) and
        inspect.ismethod(d.__init__) and
        len(inspect.getargspec(d.__init__)[0]) == 1) ]
```

Comment: I accepted this for the `try/catch`, but the comprehension still throws the `TypeError` that `<slot wrapper '__init__' of '_ui.TextField' objects> is not a Python function`

Comment: Yeah, that happens because your class doesn't have an init method at all. So I guess your `View` class doesn't have one, or it would be inherited. I edited my code to handle this... but you may want to use the Alfe answer instead :)

Comment: Yeah, I did. Try/catch is good enough. My one question is, if it doesn't have __init__, why does `ui.TextField.__init__` return a `slot wrapper` (whatever that is) instead of raising an `AttributeError`?

Comment: That's because there's a C class behind, see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15512183/1486118